# passing the '>' sign to PERL from PHP

Tags: php, perl, post, character, parameter-passing

I would like to use PHP to pass two values (I get from a php form) into a perl script in order to process these. **I am able to do this just fine with all characters but not the '>' sign**, what can I do to repair this..?

This is my php code:

```
<?php   
    $val="$_POST['val']";
    $val2="$_POST['val2']";
      system("/usr/bin/perl script.pl $val $val2",$retval); 
    if($retval!=0){
        echo ("<p> There was an unknown error.");
    }
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @po_taka already mentioned you need to sanitize $_POST data, use this the PHP function **[escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg)**.

```
system("/usr/bin/perl script.pl ".escapeshellarg($val)." ".escapeshellarg($val2),$retval);
```

Comment: Probably also worth adding `' '` around the argument (or `" "` if on windows as suggested by @po_taka.  A space in the text might well confuse the `script.pl`

Answer (score 1):

```
system("/usr/bin/perl script.pl '$val' '$val2'",$retval);
```

If you have `'` char in $var1 or $var2, you should escape it.

Anyway, passing $_POST, without sanitize, is very very dangerous!

Comment: Perhaps you could give example of quoting '